# How to fully overwrite an amp-state in AMP-HTML?

Tags: amp-html

I need to overwrite an `amp-state`.

For example:

```
<amp-state id="myState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "foo": 1,
      "bar": 2
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<button on="tab:AMP.setState({myState: {foo: 3}})">Set</button>
```

The result of this action is this:

```
{
  "foo": 3,
  "bar": 2
}
```

I would like to get this:

```
{
  "foo": 3,
}
```

Is this possible without explicitly setting `bar` to`null`?
If I need to remove tens of properties?

Comment: No, it's not possible as stated [here](https://github.com/kmh287/amphtml/blob/cee2e55f4d11985050c477d31578d41bd9616822/extensions/amp-bind/amp-bind.md#removing-a-variable).
What's the use case?

Comment: @kul3r4, in a list of items were the user can select all items that would like to remove from the list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, if the user is already selecting the ones that want to remove from the list, what is the complexity of setting all of them to null?

Comment: Thanks for replay, yes, your are right :)